# Get 2 items from each item in list python class

Tags: python, list, class

Currently I work in Python 3.8.0.
I made a list with 4 random items, and now I want to get the name and the HP from each item in that list.
I've tried **repr**, but then I've got an error returned non-string (type tuple), and I don't know how to solve this issue.
What have I to do to only get the name and hp without the rest of the string.
My code below:

```
Class1
def __repr__(self):
return self.__naam, self.__hit_points
main.py
    for i in l_vier_superhelden_lijst:
    print(i)
```

Output without def **repr**(self):

```
Ik ben Hulk
Mijn type is: Human
Mijn HP is: 2000
```

The output I want:

```
Hulk 
2000
```

Comment: The code is not executable, can you tidy up your formatting so that it can be run by copy-pasting just that code?  It looks like there is already a __str__ method that is interacting with your examples.  You also probably would be better off just printing the values themselves in this case

Comment: It's not clear from the question what you want. What is `l_vier_superhelden_lijst`, a single instance of your class or a list of instances? The output you want looks like you want to iterate over the attributes of a single object, which is possible, though a bit strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__repr__` is reserved for returning string representations of an object, you have to return a string from that method.

You could achieve what you're doing with:

```
def get_name_and_health(self) -> str:
    return str(self.__name) + "\n" + str(self__hit_points)
```

```
for thing in list_of_things: 
    print(thing.get_name_and_health())
```

Comment: How can I call that function in the for loop?

Comment: Updated the original answer with what I think you're asking for.